# How to use Decimal with precision and scale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decimal

Using rails 3.0.3, I migrated a `decimal` column in my base using the following migration:

```
 change_table :products do |t|
   t.change :price, :decimal, :precision => 10, :scale => 2
   # other code
 end
```

The migration works ok, but I can still store value like 4.64564 where it should only store 4.65

On top of that, except in the migration file I created, schema.rb does not contain info about scale/precision.

Why does rails accept precision/scale migration to ignore it?

Answer (score 3):

You should try with

```
change_column :products, :price, :decimal, :precision => 10, :scale => 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, please look at that lib:
https://github.com/dmgr/dmg_decimal

With it you can use it in a model like that:

```
def price= val
  self[:price] = Dmg::Decimal.real(val, scale: 2, precision: 10).to_d if val.present?
end
```